# Unable to make operations in supabase when stripe webhook fires

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, vercel, next.js13, supabase

My ultimate goal is to do the following:

- have user choose stripe subscription and sign up (works successfully)
- when the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event fires, I want to increment a value in the db associated to the stripe customer id. (not working)

When the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event fires, I successfully trigger my endpoint at `api/webhooks`. This works up until i try to make call to supabase or back out to stripe, but seem to fail silently.
No logs in supabase or vercel, no errors either. Which leads me to believe this is a session issue, but i still think id see an error.

FWIW, I started out with the [vercel Stripe Subscriptions template](https://github.com/vercel/nextjs-subscription-payments).

Here is my updated code

`app/api/webhooks/route.ts`:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
import { stripe } from '@/utils/stripe';
import { headers } from 'next/headers';
import { adjustProjectSupportHoursByCustomerId, getStripeProduct } from "@/utils/supabase-admin";
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
import { Database } from '@/types_db';

// Note: supabaseAdmin uses the SERVICE_ROLE_KEY which you must only use in a secure server-side context
// as it has admin privileges and overwrites RLS policies!
const supabaseAdmin = createClient<Database>(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL || '',
  process.env.SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY || '',
  {
    auth: {
      persistSession: false,
      autoRefreshToken: false,
      detectSessionInUrl: false
    }
  }
);

const relevantEvents = new Set([
  // 'product.created',
  // 'product.updated',
  // 'price.created',
  // 'price.updated',
  // 'checkout.session.completed',
  // 'customer.subscription.created',
  // 'customer.subscription.updated',
  // 'customer.subscription.deleted',
  'invoice.payment_succeeded',
]);


// pass a negative number to subtract from the support_hours
// pass a positive number to add to the support_hours
const updateProjectHours = async (projectId: string, newHours: string): Promise<boolean> => {
  console.log('updating project hours for project: ', projectId);
  const additionalHours = Number(newHours);
  console.log('additionalHours: ', additionalHours);
  if (Number(additionalHours) === 0) return false;
  // get project by the stripe_customer_id
  const { data: project, error: err } = await supabaseAdmin
    .from('projects')
    .select()
    .eq('id', projectId)
    .eq('active', true)
    .single();
  console.log('getting project...');
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error getting project: ' + projectId + ' Error: ' + err);
    console.error('Error:', err);
    return false;
  }
  
  let calculatedHours = Number(project?.support_hours) - additionalHours;
  console.log('calculatedHours: ', calculatedHours);
  const hrsFixed = calculatedHours.toFixed(2);
  console.log('hrsFixed: ', hrsFixed);

  // update the support_hours for the project
  const { error } = await supabaseAdmin
    .from('projects')
    .update({ support_hours: `${hrsFixed}` })
    .eq('id', project?.id);

  if (error) {
    console.log('Error updating project: ' + projectId + ' Error: ' + error.message);
    console.error('updateProjectHours Error:', error);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}


const updateSupportHours = async (
  invoice: Stripe.Invoice,
  checkoutSession: Stripe.Checkout.Session
) => {
  console.log('hit updateSupportHours...');
  const lineItems = invoice.lines.data;
  let newHours = 0;
  console.log('lineItem: ', lineItems[0]);
  lineItems.forEach( async (
    item: Stripe.InvoiceLineItem,
    index: number,
    array: Stripe.InvoiceLineItem[]
  ) => {
    const priceMetaData = item?.price?.metadata;
    console.log('priceMetaData: ', priceMetaData);
    if (priceMetaData && priceMetaData?.support === 'true') {
      // add all the support hours from the line items
      if (priceMetaData?.supportHours && Number(priceMetaData?.supportHours) > 0) {
        newHours += Number(priceMetaData?.supportHours as string);
        console.log('newHours: ', newHours);
      } else {
        console.log('No support hours found for product');
      }

      if (newHours > 0) {
        // const adjusted = await adjustProjectSupportHoursByCustomerId(
        //   checkoutSession.customer as string,
        //   `-${newHours}`
        // );
        try {
          console.log('getting project info for customer: ', checkoutSession.customer);
          const { data: project, error: projectError } = await supabaseAdmin
            .from('projects')
            .select()
            .eq('stripe_customer_id', checkoutSession.customer)
            .eq('active', true)
            // .single();
          
          console.log('project: ', project);

          if (projectError) {
            console.error('Error:', projectError);
            return false;
          }
          console.log('updating project hours...');

          const adjusted = await updateProjectHours(project[0]?.id, `-${newHours}`);
          console.log('adjusted: ', adjusted);

          if (!adjusted) {
            throw new Error('Support hours not adjusted for customer: ' + checkoutSession.customer);
          }
          console.log('adjusted hours!');
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error adjusting support hours:', error);
          throw error;
        }
      } else {
        console.log('No support hours to adjust');
      }
    }
  });
};

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const body = await req.text();
  const sig = headers().get('Stripe-Signature') as string;
  const webhookSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;
  let event: Stripe.Event;

  try {
    if (!sig || !webhookSecret) return;
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig, webhookSecret);
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.error(`❌ Error message: ${err.message}`);
    return new Response(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`, { status: 400 });
  }

  if (relevantEvents.has(event.type)) {
    try {
      switch (event.type) {
        case 'invoice.payment_succeeded':
          const checkoutSession = event.data.object as Stripe.Checkout.Session;
          console.log('checkoutSession -> Customer ID: ', checkoutSession.customer);
          const invoice = event.data.object as Stripe.Invoice;
          const invoiceBillingReason = invoice.billing_reason;
          console.log('invoiceBillingReason: ', invoiceBillingReason);
          if (invoiceBillingReason === 'subscription_create' || invoiceBillingReason === 'subscription_cycle') {
            await updateSupportHours(invoice, checkoutSession);
          }
          break;
        default:
          throw new Error('Unhandled relevant event!');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return new Response(
        'Webhook handler failed. View your nextjs function logs.',
        {
          status: 400
        }
      );
    }
  }
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({ received: true }));
}
```

The problem is not clear to me

I've tried using both session options with supabase, but no luck.
Both approaches work fine locally, but wont update db values in production.

Comment: I've narrowed down the issue to this call 
`const product = await getStripeProduct(
        item?.price?.product as string
      );`
For some reason the webhook fails at this point with no error or log